# error: out-of-line definition of 'test' does not match any declaration in 'B<dim>'

Tags: c++, macos, templates, inheritance, virtual

I have a small problem that is killing me!! I don't know what seems to be wrong with the below code. I should be able to implement the function that is inherited from the super class, shouldn't I? but I get `error: out-of-line definition of 'test' does not match any declaration in 'B<dim>'`

```
template <int dim>
class A 
{
public:
  virtual double test() const ;
};

template <int dim>
class B : public A <dim>
{
};

template <int dim>
double B<dim>::test () const
{
  return 0;
}
```

I am on a Mac using clang (Apple LLVM version 5.1).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
template <int dim>
class B : public A <dim>
{
public:
     virtual double test () const;
};

// Function definition
template <int dim>
double B<dim>::test () const
{
  return 0;
}
```

You still need to *define* the function declared the class declaration.

Comment: But doesn't redeclaring the function defeat the purpose of inheritance? I want a super class to define all the necessary functions that many sub classes declare. I don't want to repeat the decleration again! Also, wouldn't your fix hide the A::test function?

Comment: @FahadAlrashed No! If you don't redeclare it, how the compiler should know class `B` provides it's own implementation. _'I don't want to repeat the decleration again!'_ To write valid c++ code, you'll have to!

Comment: Thank you. I still think that C++ should be clever enough to know that the function is being overridden.

Comment: @FahadAlrashed I have edited the answer. C++ does have this feature to explicitly specify you want to `override`. Answerer probably forgot about it.

Comment: @FahadAlrashed : The constructor of B needs to know the function is being overriden, in order to set the vtable accordingly. But, that constructor and the test() definition may be in different compilation units.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you are trying to define function test outside the class definition of class B. You have to declare it at first in the class

```
template <int dim>
class B : public A <dim>
{
   double test() const;
};
```

Comment: Again .. doesn't redeclaring the function defeat the purpose of inheritance? I don't see why I need to redeclare an inherited function.

Comment: @Fahad Alrashed You are trying to define a function of class B that was not declared in this class. If you want to redefine a virtual function you need to declare it in this class.

Comment: If one could declare/define a method of a function outside of a class for the purpose of overriding a base implementation, who's to say that it couldn't be defined/declared in some other file altogether? This would be a mess as it would allow arbitrary overriding of methods anywhere and lead to unmaintainable sludge.